# How should sonar be configured to work with StyleCop 4.7

Tags: c#, sonarqube, stylecop, static-code-analysis

I am attempting to get sonar to work with StyleCop 4.7 and am having a few issues.

1) When I set the location of StyleCop in the Sonar settings, Sonar fails to run and therefor fails my CI builds.  It seems that Sonar is unable to find the assemblies that are compiled as part of StyleCop 4.7

2) I do not see a way to get the rules that are available in version 4.7 that are not available in 4.4 .  Meaning, I want to enable rules that are avaible in version 4.7 but do not show up as options to enable and prioritize in the quality profiles of sonar.

I am trying to run sonar analysis on a C# project and it successfully runs using the default version of the c# plugins.  I am running version 2.13.1 of Sonar.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 1rst problem, I can't help you more if you do not provide an excerpt of the log file. What you can also do is to run the analysis in debug mode ('-X') so that you can find the exact command launched for StyleCop and try to relaunch it manually to get more information about the failure.

For the 2nd problem, until we have updated the StyleCop plugin, you can add the missing rules in Sonar using the [guide we put on the Wiki](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C-Sharp+custom+checks).

Comment: Thank you for the answer Fabrice.  I think that my first problem is also related to the answer you gave for #2.  Do you know when the next scheduled release of the C# plugins will be?

Comment: We don't have a release date yet for next version 1.4 (version 1.3 has just been released). However, I created the following ticket that you can follow to be notified when things change: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1773